# Change position to the default main menu of a theme

Tags: drupal, menu

Maybe the question is silly, but I just start to look into Drupal and I cannot find any relatives information on the web.
I have installed a theme (corporate clean) that use a inline main navigation just after the logo and before the gallery.

I would like to change that menu position. Move the main menu on the left side.

But everytime I give to navigation or main menu block the 'navigation' position, I see a new block filled in with the same main menu links. 
Instead I want the first link be relocated in the left side.

How could I do that?

(btw the theme has even a navigation block, but it cannot understand how it work exactly..)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu is usualy inserted in the page.tpl.php you can move it around in this file. 
Alternatively you can go to admin/appearance/settings/yourTheme and turn off "Main menu" and "Secondary menu" and use the [Menu block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module to position menus where you want them.

Comment: Cool, so i can directly edit the php files. Is this a normal Drupal way to work? Touch the core files?

Comment: Do not edit the core files but you can edit the themes in sites/all/themes if your theme dosnt have a page.tpl.php file you can copy it out of one of the core themes and into yours

Comment: yes sorry i meant core file of a theme. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the main menu (that is initially in the "navigation" area, like horizontally) in a **new column on the left side**, like vertically?

If yes, just go in `administration>structure>blocks` and drag your "Main Menu" in "**First Lateral Bar**" area (under Content, in Coporate Clean theme). Save and check the result.

If not, do you want your Main menu just like it is now but **aligned left** instead of right? If yes, just play with **CSS**.

Comment: The first solution is the right one. The problem is that the main menu is not visible in the "navigation" area under the blocks section. If I add main menu to "First sidebar" I just create a new menu so I have two main menu on my page